# MAMP crashes immediately on launch

Tags: mamp

I was using MAMP to work on a Wordpress site on my Mac, when I had the brilliant idea to delete everything (all the files located in htdocs folder and also the whole database). From there MAMP has stopped connecting to the servers, so I've uninstalled and reinstalled the app, and now the result is that when I try to start MAMP, the app crashes immediately.

Comment: More uninstalling is the best option (I think). Delete the entire mamp folder and all config files for all servers (and maybe even uninstall the different servers)

Comment: Is there a way to manually delete the MAMP config files and to uninstall the servers? I tried several times to uninstall and reinstall MAMP, and if I launch it from the terminal I can see this error: "Unable to load nib file: MainMenu, exiting". Can't understand what's a nib file and where to find it.